# Correction methods for spurious correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, spurious-correlation

I'm investigating the relationship between A/B and A*. I've found that higher A/B scores lead to lower A scores. Obviously however there is spurious correlation between A/B and A, and if that spurious correlation could be removed, the already negative correlation between A/B & A would become larger. Are there standard methods for subtracting the effects of spurious correlation? My thinking was that one rule of thumb approach would be to compare the sample to random data with the same distribution of A & B and then look at the difference between the B stats. Is this an acceptable approach?

*For anyone interested A is median white wages and B is median black wages and the sample is cities.

Comment: Suppose you are interested in a relationship between $y$ and $x$, namely, how $x$ is affecting $y$. If you can cast your problem into this framework, you may look into multiple linear regression of the form $y = \beta_0+\beta_1 x + \gamma z + \varepsilon$ where $z$ is a control variable that is not of primary interest and $\varepsilon$ is random disturbance. In your example, the "spurious correlation" effect could perhaps be dealt with by accounting for it by using a control variable $z$.

Comment: Then A is negatively correlated to B, is it not? Which $R^2$ has higher magnitude A/B with A, or A with B?